# Using txt file to download the File from FTP location in Batch Mode capability

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ftp, batch

I need help regarding downloading the files from FTP Server to the Local Server.

for downloading i need to use the FTP In batch Mode capability and I have a txt file with with all the files which needs to be downloaded.

**file.txt**

```
cap/media/101/101.mp4
cap/media/102/102.mp4
cap/media/103/103.mp4
cap/media/104/104.mp4
cap/media/105/105.mp4
cap/media/106/106.mp4
```

`cap/media/101` is the folder structure inside the FTP user root and 101.mp4 is the file.

so the folder structure for 1000 of file is same and the mp4 is located as listed.

so i need a bash script which can run in Batch mode capability and download all the files automatically to the local Storage.

I have created that script but it is not working, hopefully someone can give me some hints,

```
###########################
HOST="ftp.remote.com"
USER="media"
PASSWORD="test"
FILE="/tmp/list.txt"
###########################



 cd /tmp/
while read p; do 
pt=$(dirname $p);
h="/"
pth=$pt$h
mxf=$(basename $p);
#echo $pth;
#echo $mxf; 
ftp -n -v >> /tmp/filetransfer.log 2>&1 $HOST <<EOF
binary
user $USER $PASSWORD
prompt
lcd /tmp/media
cd $pth
mget $mxf
quit
EOF
done < /tmp/list.txt
```

and that is the output of the FTP Can you please help me here , I am not understanding what excatly i am doing wrong.

```
Connected to ftp.remote.com
220-FTPD
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
331 User media OK. Password required
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
Interactive mode off.
Local directory now /tmp/media
250 OK. Current directory is cap/media
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout.
```

I am having this error: **221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.**

thank you for any comment and advice in Advance.

Comment: Can you share the error, that you see?

Comment: `Connected to ftp.remote.com.
220-FTPD
220 This is a private system - No anonymous login
200 TYPE is now ASCII
331 User media OK. Password required
230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
Interactive mode off.
221-Goodbye. You uploaded 0 and downloaded 0 kbytes.
221 Logout`
this is the Output, so now files are being downloading.

Comment: So its downloading now?

Comment: @nisheet , it didnt download, as you see the upload and download is 0 kbyets

Comment: Instead of passing file names does `mget *` work?

Comment: i didnt try with * , i can give a try just now `cap/media/101` this is the folder path

Comment: Also one major flow I think is that $FILE is replaced by `/tmp/list.txt` which then it looks for on the FTP server, doesn't find and exits out.

You will need to specify file names you would want to download, or modify the script to read the filenames from $FILE, in the mget understandable format.

Comment: mget $FILE will expand to `mget /tmp/list.txt` which is not what you need. What you need is content of `/tmp/list.txt` to be fed to mget.

Comment: yes, you are right , i got this List from my Cloud FTP and thats the folder structure and the file name.
I am also trying to cut the Folder name and the File Name from the Each line Just last question about the Batch mode. how can i switch to it.

Comment: Try something like this

   ` fileList=``cat /tmp/list.txt`` `
    `mget "$fileList"`

Comment: when i try cat , it just display all the line on my shell

Comment: I am unable to to type here due to formatting issues, you need to quote the `cat /tmp/list.txt` within backquotes (That symbol is below ~ on keyboard). What that effectively does is gets output of the cat command and stores in fileList.

Comment: @Nisheet, can you please help me here, i am not understanding what is wrong here, why its not downloading the files

Comment: Just looking over it pretty quickly.  You can set the `pt` to `pt=$(dirname $p)/;` and it will add the `/` to the end of the folder.  You wouldn't need the `h=` or `pth=` at that moment.  Your cd command would then just be `cd $pt`.  Not sure why when you are running your script it is not going into the 101, 102, etc. folders like it should.

Comment: It's moving to the folder but somehow it's not finding the file to download and if I use only GET command instead of MGET then it say file not found and it says in log 101.mp4_ ,

Comment: And it just shows _ at the end of the file and I don't get it why it comes there. And why it doesn't find the file.

Comment: Weird.  It is putting an underscore `_` at the end which doesn't exist.  Try changing the variables to this:  `pt="$(dirname "$p")/";` and `mxf="$(basename "$p")";`  then when you cd, only use `cd "$pt"` maybe there is special characters that it is not reading right.

Answer (score 0):

Follow upto the comments this should probably work:

> ```
> HOST="ftp.remote.com"
> USER="media"
> PASSWORD="test"
> FILE=`cat /tmp/list.txt`
> cd /tmp/localstorage
>
> ftp -n -v >> /tmp/ftptransfer.log 2>&1 $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
> ascii
> user $USER $PASSWORD
> prompt
> mget $FILE
> quit
> END_SCRIPT
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following script to avoid errors with filenames which contains a space:

```
#!/bin/bash

host=ftp://ftp.local
username=user
password=pw
cmd="curl -O -u ${username}:${password} ${host}/"
cd public_html
cat ~/list.txt | while read files ; do $cmd"${files}" | echo ${files};
done | tee -a ~/ftp.log
```