# Hold the sed output into Variable

Tags: command-line, bash, keyboard, sed

I am creating a bash script which read the Txt file and with While Loop and then do some tricks with SED to get the string out it and the Value of string needs to be hold into another Varibale.

Here is my Script.

```
while read p; do
PATH="$p | sed -r 's|.*media/([^/]+).*|\1|'"
#FILE = "$p | awk -F"/" '{print $4}'"
echo $PATH
#echo $FILE
#echo $p
done < /tmp/list.txt
```

**List.txt**

```
cap/media/101/101.mp4
cap/media/102/102.mp4
cap/media/103/103.mp4
cap/media/104/104.mp4
cap/media/105/105.mp4
cap/media/106/106.mp4
```

thank you

Comment: **Never** use `PATH` as the name for one of your own shell script variables - in fact, it's best to avoid all-caps names altogether.

Comment: I would use awk instead of sed. I can see that you thought about it but you made some mistake in the declaration of the variable... You can't have any space between the name of the variable and =.

Comment: Why use`sed` when `dirname` or `basename` does a better job in less lines of code:   `while read p; do echo $(dirname $p); done` returns folder names and `while read p; do echo $(basename $p); done` returns file names.

Comment: ... or even set read it as slash delimited data `while IFS=/ read -r _ _ p _; do echo "$p"; done < List.txt`. If you *must* use a regex then even that could be done in bash `while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ (.*media\/)([^/]*)(/.*) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"; done < List.txt`

Comment: @steeldriver, I didnt get your Point. I need the value of SED into another Varibale because that is the Path to Directory, in which i will CD after holding the value

Comment: You get it in a variable - either `$p` or `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}` - without resorting to `sed`

Comment: sorry @steeldriver, i am not sure how i get the `$p` and `${BASH_REMATCH[2]}`, Can you please help me here

Comment: can i please have any Help i am not getting it through

Comment: I don't know how to use the `${BASH_REMATCH[]}`, but what I wrote earlier works for extracting the folder from the text using the `dirname` command.  `while read p; do pth=$(dirname $p); echo $pth; done < List.txt`

Comment: Hello @Terrance, Thank you for the help, But i also need the last part from the string `cap/media/101/101.mp4` into other Variable which can be `$filename=101.mp4` and of course this dynamic and thats why i was trying to do it with `sed` or `awk`.

thank you!

Comment: thank you for the Tip, I have Found the Basename command to get the answer  which was looking for! `while read p; do 
pth=$(dirname $p);
mxf=$(basename $p);
#echo $pth;
echo $mxf; done < /tmp/list.txt`

Comment: Good, glad that helped you!  =)

Comment: @Terrance, can you please help me here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/881165/using-txt-file-to-download-the-file-from-ftp-location-in-batch-mode-capability